# url not found error in laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5 with a new version of apache on ubuntu and when I try to access the page: localhost it works and if I try localhost/index.php/my_page it works but if I try localhost/my_page, it doesnt. So from searching other questions I guess my problem lies in the .htaccess file.

As per suggestions I saw online I added the rewriteBase and Options +FollowSymLinks to my .htaccess in laravel/public:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
      </IfModule>

      Options +FollowSymLinks
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /repos/kenrose/public

      # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
      RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

      # Handle Front Controller...
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
```

and this is what my apache2.conf file looks

```
    <Directory /repos/kenrose>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I've taken all the suggestions i've found about this issue. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Try to remove ur `+FollowSymLinks` part,hope it will work.

Comment: I tried and it did not work. Thats how it was originally and I had the problem and I added the +FollowSymLinks and it did not help

Comment: try to remove the Rewrite Rule ^ index.php [L],then run.I'm not sure but hope so.

Answer (score 0):

after running

```
 a2enmod rewrite
```

in the command terminal, all is well.
I don't know what this does, or what the problem was though.